# Matrix Product Operator of a Hamiltonian

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, computational-physics

I encounter a problem in finding the $W^{[1]}$ and $W^{[N]}$ for a Matrix Product Operator(MPO). Suppose the system is governed by the following Hamiltonian, we can directly write its MPO down:
\begin{equation}
H = \sum^{N}_{i} -h S^{z}_{i} ~~,~~
W^{[i]} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 I_{2 \times 2}& 0 \\
-h S^{z} & I_{2 \times 2} 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

My question is how can we get the $W^{[1]}$ and $W^{[N]}$ given an MPO $W^{[i]}$? I know the solution of this case is $W^{[1]} = [-hS^{z} ~~ I_{2 \times 2}]$ and  $W^{[N]} = [ I_{2\times 2} ~~ -hS^{z}]^{T}$. However,  I do not understand why $W^{[1]} $ and $W^{[N]}$ equal to these stuff.

Comment: *What* don't you understand?

Comment: I don't understand why given an MPO $W^{[i]}$, the corresponding $W^{[1]}$ and  $W^{[N]}$ are the last row and first column  of $W^{[1]}$ respectively.